# At any $θ$ on curve $x=a\cos{θ}+aθ \sin{θ}$,$ y=a\sin{θ}-aθ\cos{θ}$ what is distance from the origin to nomal?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The parametric equation at any point $\theta$ of a curve is:

$$x=a\cos{(\theta)}+a\theta\sin{(\theta)}, y=a\sin(\theta)-a\theta\cos{(\theta)}$$

What is its distance from the origin to its normal at any $\theta$ ?

I don't understand how I should approach this problem and what steps should I follow. I got the equation to the curve ie $x^2+y^2=a^2{(1+θ^2)}$. but I don't understand what my next step should be. Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by the point 't'????

Comment: it's in parametric form, consider it theta, i don't know how to type a theta :D

Comment: use latex, to write theta: `$\theta$`

Comment: Now, could you help me?

Comment: what does it mean a($\theta$) ? a*$\theta$ or a as a function of $\theta$?

Comment: @Navaro a times θ

Comment: @Narasimham yes.. sorry

Comment: @ShrishDutta I edited your question. Please confirm if this is in order, i.e., it reflects what you meant.

Comment: $\theta$ is parameter for involute curve , also polar coordinate for *circle*, but not *involute*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve is an **involute of circle** with radius $a$.

**Tangent of the curve:**
\begin{align*}
  \frac{dx}{d\theta}
  &= -a\sin \theta+a\theta \cos \theta+a\sin \theta \\
  &= a\theta \cos \theta \\
  \frac{dy}{d\theta}
  &= a\cos \theta+a\theta \sin \theta-a\cos \theta \\
  &= a\theta \sin \theta \\[5pt]
  \frac{dy}{dx}
  &= \frac{a\theta \sin \theta}{a\theta \cos \theta} \\[5pt]
  &= \tan \theta \\
\end{align*}

**Equation of the Normal:**
\begin{align*}
  y-(a\sin \theta-a\theta \cos \theta) &=
  -\cot \theta [x-(a\sin \theta+a\theta \cos \theta)] \\
   y\sin \theta -a\sin \theta(\sin \theta-\theta \cos \theta) &=
  -x\cos \theta +a\cos \theta(\cos \theta+\theta \sin \theta) \\
  x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta &= a (\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta) \\
  x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta &= a
\end{align*}
which has fixed distance $a$ from the origin.

[image]

Comment: $\frac{dx}{d\theta} =-a\sin\theta+a\theta\cos\theta+a\sin\theta$??

Comment: @Muralidharan Yes

Comment: in your solution, $dx/d\theta$ is given as $a\cos\theta$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The 1st and last terms cancel out. $$\color{red}{-a\sin \theta} +\color{blue}{a\theta \cos \theta} \color{red}{+a\sin \theta} = \color{blue}{a\theta \cos \theta}$$

Comment: Yes, in your solution, $dx/d\theta$ Is given as $a\cos\theta$. Should not that be $a\theta\cos\theta$?

Comment: Bugs have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{d\theta} &= a\theta\sin\theta \\
\frac{dx}{d\theta} &= a\theta \cos\theta
\end{align*}
Hence the slope of the normal at $\theta$ is $-\cot\theta$ and the equation of the normal is $x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta = a$. This is always at a distance $a$ from the origin.